USB drive mounting error after inclomplete shutdown/disconnest of the drive
I'm using an external USB disc (Western Digital, Elements 2620) for backup. After my last backup (bash script which copies the files from the internal disc to the usb drive) I didn't wait during "eject" the usb disc (I thought the operating LED of the drive was off). So it seems, the file system is somehow corrupted. :-(
I do the mounting with the file dialog manually, not by script or during startup.
Connecting the drive to a Windows PC, the OS wants to "repair" the file system on the disk. After this, the files can be accessed without problems.
Back to the Ubuntu PC I still cannot mount the drive. I always get an error message. Here is the part of the kernal log:
14:35:11 kernel: ntfs3: sdd1: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!
14:35:11 kernel: ntfs3: sdd1: It is recommened to use chkdsk.
14:35:10 kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
14:35:10 kernel:  sdd: sdd1
14:35:10 kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
14:35:10 kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
14:35:10 kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
14:35:10 kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
14:35:10 kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
14:35:10 kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 3906963456 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
14:35:10 kernel: ...ready
14:35:10 kernel: sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Spinning up disk...
14:35:07 kernel: scsi 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
14:35:07 kernel: scsi 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
14:35:07 kernel: scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 2620    1023 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
14:35:06 kernel: scsi host8: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
14:35:06 kernel: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
14:35:06 kernel: usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 5758333241393138534C5A59
14:35:06 kernel: usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 5758333241393138534C5A59
14:35:06 kernel: usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
14:35:06 kernel: usb 2-1.1: Product: Elements 2620
14:35:06 kernel: usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
14:35:06 kernel: usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=2620, bcdDevice=10.23
14:35:06 kernel: usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci

Details of my system:
OS:         Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Mainboard   ASUTeK Computer INC. M5A78L-M/USB3
Processor:  AMD Athlon IIX2 270x2

The USB drive is formatted as ntfs.
The kernel log recommends me to use "CHKDSK". I know this command from windows. But I don#t know, how or where to invoke under Ubuntu. Or is there any other useful way to to "repair" the disc? I don't want to reformat it, because I want to keep my backup. ;-)

You have to run chkdsk from Windows if format if NTFS. But you should not be backing up Linux data to NTFS as NTFS does not support Linux ownership & permissions. If just data and not any system files, you probably can reset owernship & permissions to defaults used for data. But system files have many owners, not just / (root).
